# Can't save the Full-Sized Photo on Camera Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

After I've read the Tutorial [Taking Photos Simply](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html), I tried to do it like in the tutorial.

The Problem is that on my OnePlus X it works. If I'm using other Phones like Samsung Galaxy S5 or S6 or any other device it doesn't work.

```
pictureActionIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (pictureActionIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (photoFile != null) {
        //pictureActionIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
    }
}
startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

If I delete the comment, the `data` in `onActivityResult` is `null`.
If I set the comment, the `data` looks (on Samsung device) like:

```
data = {android.content.Intent@19974} "Intent{act=inline-data dat=content://Media/external/images/media/16123 (has extras)}"
```

So, where is the problem? What do I have to change to make it working on every device?

Thank you for any help!

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the IMAGE URL also.

```
   intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, _fileUri);
```

Then you can use this file path.

**EDIT**

```
private void saveFullImage() { 
  Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.jpg");
  outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
  startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
} 

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if ((requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)) {
    // Check if the result includes a thumbnail Bitmap 
    if (data == null) {    
      // TODO Do something with the full image stored 
      // in outputFileUri. Perhaps copying it to the app folder 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: I think i do this on `Uri.fromFile(photoFile)`? I dont know it looks identical for me.

Comment: yeah as I wrote. If i delete the comments nothing happens and data is null. If I set the comments `data` in `onActivityResult` has values.

Comment: you are creating photoFile path right?
is the file on that path exists in your device storage?

Comment: is the file stored on that location is with Full Size? so you can use that file :)

Comment: Yeah but just on my OnePlus X. On other devices there is no file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102578/discussion-between-shoeb-siddique-and-raymondis).

Comment: please take a look in the chat room